# Qt: blocking & accumulating signals, emitting them afterwards

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

Consider the following types:

```
class Foo: public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
    void setA(int a) {
      if(a == m_a) 
        return;
      m_a = a;
      emit aChanged(m_a);
    }
  signals:
    void aChanged(int a);
  private:
    int m_a;
};

class Bar: public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
    void setB(int b) {
      if(b == m_b) 
        return;
      m_b = b;
      emit bChanged(m_b);
    }
  signals:
    void bChanged(int b);
  private:
    int m_b;
};
```

A separate part of the code needs to update `Foo::a` and `Bar::b` atomically: that is, given

```
void updateState(Foo& foo, Bar& bar) { 
  auto [a, b] = someComplicatedComputation();
  foo.setA(a);
  bar.setB(b);
}
```

some objects in the code should never be able to see the intermediary state when `foo.setA(a);` has been called and `bar.setB(b);` hasn't been called yet, as this produces an unpleasant discontinuity.

The following solution does not work for me:

```
void updateState(Foo& foo, Bar& bar) { 
  auto [a, b] = someComplicatedComputation();
  {
    QSignalBlocker blockFoo{&foo}, blockBar{&bar};
    foo.setA(a);
    bar.setB(b);
  }
  foo.aChanged(a);
  bar.bChanged(b);
}
```

because `Foo` and `Bar` may send various signals according to more complicated business logic than my toy example, and I do not want `updateState` to depend on such implementation details of `Foo` and `Bar` nor have to duplicate their internal logic on which signal must be sent when.

What I would like is to have Foo and Bar emit their signals normally but intercept them, store them, and then send them as a bulk afterwards once I am done with my state update.

Comment: `if(a != m_a) return;` ... shouldn't it be `if(a == m_a) return;`?

Comment: yes aha, fixing

Comment: "What I would like is to have Foo and Bar emit their signals normally but intercept them, store them, and then send them as a bulk afterwards once I am done with my state update." ... no, I do not think this can be done in any way. I am afraid you need to redesign your code to fulfill your needs.

Comment: Even if you can have what you described at the end, that does not guarantee that the intermediary state will not be seen from elsewhere. If you want to do it properly, you may have to redesign. If not, then adding blockSignal flag to `setA` argument should be enough.

Comment: "that does not guarantee that the intermediary state will not be seen from elsewhere."  => this is a single-threaded use-case, so yes it does. Everything happens in a single event loop on the main thread.

Comment: What you are looking for is -- as far as I can see -- some kind of data write transaction.  That being the case you probably need a signal that can be used to signify a 'commit' request, whereby the data updates accumulated/collated thus far can be forwarded to the receivers.

Comment: Yes, an atomic transaction would be the proper "term-of-art" I guess. It looks that there's nothing to help this in Qt... will look into building my own.